# How can I load a huge image with pygame as a background?

Tags: python, image, background, pygame

I'm making a fighting game in pygame but whenever I load a background (940x680 PNG) the program starts to lag really badly, here is my code:

```
#import section
import os
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *

#end of import section

#initiazing pygame
pygame.init()
print "Loaded Pygame 100%"

#lengths
width, height = 940,680

#opening window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

#position
background = [0,0]


#loading images
back = pygame.image.load("resources/image/Back.png")

print "Loaded graphics 100%"


while 1:



    #clear to reload
    screen.fill(0)

    #drawing background
    screen.blit(back, background )

    #update
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This may be a newbie question but I just started so yeah...

Comment: I'm not super familiar with pygame, but isn't that redrawing the background every frame?

Comment: That's the problem thought, i don't know how to not redraw the background every time

Comment: Can't you just update things that are on screen, instead of clearing it and redrawing everything?

Comment: how do you do that ? :(

Comment: Try reading this:
http://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf

Should be helpful, as it answered a few other people's pygame questions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you must keep redrawing the background if you are going to add something to it. Because if you draw, lets say.. a rectangle, then if you move the rectangle, you will now have 2 rectangles on screen instead of 1.

Comment: How exactly does your program lag? It does nothing but drawing the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pygame you need to use this code you wrote.

```
#clear to reload
screen.fill(0)

#drawing background
screen.blit(back, background )

#update
pygame.display.flip()
```

If you add a player to the screen and then move him. You will notice that unless you redraw the background, you will see the character more than once.

Pygame doesn't just let you add an image to the screen and move it around, you must redraw the background to get rid of a previous frame.

Another thing you should add to your code is a wait.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30

while 1:
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

This will set the frame rate. I'd say you would generally want this at 30 - 60 frames, depending on the game / hardware.

Your current program is probably redrawing the frame a several hundred times, so this will definately add lag.

When I checked this on my pc `Ubuntu 12.04` without a background. i.e. A Black screen.

My frame rate was between `1000 - 2000 FPS`.

Comment: *you must redraw the background to get rid of a previous frame.*: yes, but you don't have to redraw the *entire* background (look into pygame's `DirtySprite` and `LayeredDirty`).

Comment: I'll take a look. I think that the users problem here is his probably his frame rate.

Comment: Yes, that's the main issue. That and the fact that he does not clear the event queue.